# Creating a custom Rails tinyMCE plugin: editor.ui is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I want to add a custom plugin to a rails backed tinyMCE editor, however in the console I get `editor.ui is undefined` and it fails

If I comment out any code relating to `editor.ui` in the config.js file then the editor loads and using the 'Help' plugin I can see that my plugin is loading fine from the `getMetadata` function

/config/tinymce.yml

```
toolbar:
    - bold italic underline superscript subscript underline | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | hr | forecolor | backcolor | table | myplugin | image | help
plugins:
  - link table lists textcolor myplugin image imagetools help
```

app/assets/javascripts/tinymce/plugins/myplugin/plugin.js
(this is just copied directly from https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/ changing "example" for "myplugin")

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
  tinymce.PluginManager.add("myplugin", function(editor, url) {
    var openDialog = function () {
      return editor.windowManager.open({
        title: "Example plugin",
        body: {
          type: "panel",
          items: [
            {
              type: "input",
              name: "title",
              label: "Title"
            }
          ]
        },
        buttons: [
          {
            type: "cancel",
            text: "Close"
          },
          {
            type: "submit",
            text: "Save",
            primary: true
          }
        ],
        onSubmit: function (api) {
          var data = api.getData();
          // Insert content when the window form is submitted
          editor.insertContent("Title: " + data.title);
          api.close();
        }
      });
    };

    // Add a button that opens a window
    editor.ui.registry.addButton("myplugin", {
      text: "My button",
      onAction: function () {
        // Open window
        openDialog();
      }
    });

    // Adds a menu item, which can then be included in any menu via the menu/menubar configuration
    editor.ui.registry.addMenuItem("myplugin", {
      text: "Example plugin",
      onAction: function() {
        // Open window
        openDialog();
      }
    });

    return {
      getMetadata: function () {
        return  {
          name: "Example plugin",
          url: "http://exampleplugindocsurl.com"
        };
      }
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of TinyMCE are you using? This code works fine on our fiddle website:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/PGgaab

Comment: Yes, that was it thanks. I was using v4. I didn't think the V5 API would be so radically different - that will teach me to read the docs properly! For anyone else that might get this problem - I had to explicitly update the tinymce-rails gem to 5.0.4 by adding this line to my gemfile `gem 'tinymce-rails', '>= 5.0.4'` then running `bundle install`. Updating the gem in the normal way using `bundle update tinymce-rails` only updated it to v4.9.0

Comment: We tried to keep the core API the same, but yes the UI was completely rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full code you are using it will be hard to say for sure but document ready in jQuery is likely firing well before TinyMCE itself is initialized.  If that is the case you can't use a TinyMCE API to add a plugin before TinyMCE is initialized.

I would, as that documentation page suggests, place the plugin code in a file and load it like all other TinyMCE plugins.  TinyMCE will get the plugins at the correct time in its initialization process and this would no longer be an issue.

Comment: If the TinyMCE script hadn't loaded `tinymce.PluginManager` would also be undefined though 

Comment: Looks like you have your answer from Spyder.  As an aside the TinyMCE script could be loaded so the TinyMCE global object exists but trying to use something like `editor` (or `activeEditor`) could fail if TinyMCE has not been initialized yet.